# Using a string to switch visible states in itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boolean, itemtemplate, visible

I have data that gets displayed in gridview.  If I'm pulling it from one table I want it to be read/write, but from the other just read.  I have a SqlDataSource that can spit out some text based on the origin, and yes the text it spits out is accurate.  So I put a label and a textbox in an itemtemplate in gridview, and both have visible properties set to a public bool.

The problem is that this doesn't always line up. Sometimes on data of one property switches to the other form (ie, read-only data is displayed as a textbox), but it's not everytime so it's not a simple "screwed up my if statement" problem.  The display state will often be the opposite of the displayed text.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Next Price" SortExpression="newdata">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ReadWrite" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("newdata", "{0:N2}") %>' Width="60px"
            class="calculate" onchange="calculate()"
            Visible='<%# ShowBox %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="ReadOnly" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("newdata", "{0:N2}") %>'
            Visible='<%# ShowLabel %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The code behind it:

```
protected void MasterDisplay_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSourceSelectArguments sr = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
    DataView dv = (DataView)CheckForCommit.Select(sr);
    if (dv.Count != 0)
        CommittedOrNot.Text = dv[0][0].ToString();
    //for displaying where data is pulled from
}

public bool ShowBox
{
    get
    {
        return (CommittedOrNot.Text == "This has not yet been committed.");
    }
    private set { }
}

public bool ShowLabel
{
    get { return (CommittedOrNot.Text != "This has not yet been committed."); }
    private set { } 
}
```

Any ideas what's causing this disconnect?

Comment: Additionally, it looks like it's using the previous version of CommittedOrNot.  Ie, if I start on a committed set(rendering ShowBox=F) and move to an uncommitted set ShowBox=F still, but then wherever I move next ShowBox=T.  CommittedOrNot.Text always shows the correct output though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add UpdateRows and a DataBind in Commit_Click